# Center UIImageView within a UIScrollView with a larger contentSize

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview, offset

I have a full screen `scrollView`, to which I add an `imageView` as subview. I want the `imageView` to be centered and scaled filling the `scrollView`'s size (that is the screen size) at the beginning, but then to allow the user to scroll the image in both directions (vertical and horizontal) with equal offsets at left, right, top and bottom.

I mean: I've set the scroll view's `contentSize` to be `CGSize(width: screenWidth + 200, height: screenHeight + 200)`, and if I run the app, I see that I am able to scroll those 200 pts of offset only to the right and to the bottom of the image. I'd like the image to be centered in the content size, and to be able to scroll it horizontally to both to the left and to the right with offset 100 pts each side (similar thing with top and bottom when scrolling vertically).

How could I achieve this?

**Note:** I'm setting all the UI in code, I'm not using storyboards nor `xib` files

Answer (score 1):

You may find it easier / more intuitive to use constraints and auto-layout rather than `screenWidth` and `screenHeight`:

```
//
//  CenteredScrollViewController.swift
//  SW4Temp
//
//  Created by Don Mag on 4/18/18.
//

import UIKit

class CenteredScrollViewController: UIViewController {

    let theScrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let v = UIScrollView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        return v
    }()

    let theImageView: UIImageView = {
        let v = UIImageView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        return v
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // add the scrollView to the main view
        view.addSubview(theScrollView)

        // add the imageView to the scrollView
        theScrollView.addSubview(theImageView)

        // pin the scrollView to all four sides
        theScrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
        theScrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
        theScrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
        theScrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true

        // constrain the imageView's width and height to the scrollView's width and height
        theImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theScrollView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.0).isActive = true
        theImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theScrollView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1.0).isActive = true

        // set the imageView's top / bottom / leading / trailing anchors
        // this *also* determines the scrollView's contentSize (scrollable area)
        // with 100-pt padding on each side
        theImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theScrollView.topAnchor, constant: 100.0).isActive = true
        theImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theScrollView.bottomAnchor, constant: -100.0).isActive = true
        theImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theScrollView.leadingAnchor, constant: 100.0).isActive = true
        theImageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theScrollView.trailingAnchor, constant: -100.0).isActive = true

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        // set the scrollView's contentOffset (to center the imageView)
        theScrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)
    }

}
```

Comment: This worked for me, the core thing was to set anchors on allsides as well as width and height anchor

Answer (score 0):

You can move only down and right because your current content offset is 0,0 so top left - thus you can move down 200 and right 200.

What you want is to be scrolled 1/2 of vertical padding and 1/2 of horizontal padding, so in your case you would do `scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)`

Also for everything to work, `UIImageView` has to be same size as `scrollView`'s contentSize, so bigger than screen size.

Given the comments what I think you want is the image to fill the screen and then user could scroll outside of bounds of the image, then you just need to make `UIImageView`'s size be size of the screen its x and y coordinates to be same as `contentOffset` of the `scrollView` so (100, 100).

Here is the video of the sample app doing this:
https://dzwonsemrish7.cloudfront.net/items/2v361r2p0O2j1D3x3W10/Screen%20Recording%202018-04-19%20at%2002.32%20PM.mov

Comment: Thanks, but actually what I want is to have "blank" offsets around the image, I don't want the image to fill the scroll view's content size. On the other hand, it seems that the `contentOffset` shows such offsets from the beginning. I'd also like to show the image filling the screen size at the beginning, then being able to scroll it with those offsets.

Comment: Is this what is needed or am I missing something? https://dzwonsemrish7.cloudfront.net/items/2v361r2p0O2j1D3x3W10/Screen%20Recording%202018-04-19%20at%2002.32%20PM.mov

Comment: @AppsDev is this what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

try this in
Swift 4.* or 5.*

```
let maxScale = self.imageScrollView.maximumZoomScale
let minScale = self.imageScrollView.minimumZoomScale

if let imageSize = imageView.image?.size{
    let topOffset: CGFloat = (boundsSize.height - minScale * imageSize.height ) / 2
    let leftOffset: CGFloat = (boundsSize.width - minScale * imageSize.width ) / 2
    self.imageScrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: topOffset, left: leftOffset, bottom: 0, right: 0)
}
```